# Message tag in Thunderbird disappears when message moved from inbox to trash

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I am using Thunderbird 68.8 on Debian Buster and I have created tags with different colors.

I have created filters, so that messages are taged upon receiving, with appropriate tag.

All works well when new message is received. But when I delete the message, in trash it no longer appears tagged (the color disappears)

#### How can I keep tags, regardless in which folder the message is?

**UPDATE**: After troubleshooting the problem, I found the following behavior:

1. When new email arrives in inbox, it is properly tagged.
2. When I delete the email, it is moved to trash, and it is still tagged in trash.
3. But, as soon as I click on this email in trash, or actually on any other email in trash folder, the tag suddenly disappears.

Comment: I use tags myself and on my end they stay on the message after deleting too. That makes me wonder, if you move the message back, do the tags reappear? If so, the deleted items folder might not have the right columns visible or something else is different between the trash folder and inbox.

Comment: @LPChip - the tag disappears. When I right-click on the message in trash, and choose tags, there are no tags selected.

Comment: Could be a bug in Thunderbird. I'm not using the most recent build, so maybe its something that changed or a bug. You could see if this is the case by testing it in an old portable installation. I use the latest 60.9 version

Comment: @LPChip - I have done more troubleshooting, and update my post.

Comment: Do you have a rule on the trash folder maybe? Its also possible that your mailserver actually does this. If you create a new folder in your inbox, ex trash 2, then in account configuration specify that folder as the new trash folder, does the same happen? It may very well be that your mail provider does something special to the trash folder.

Comment: @LPChip I don't have any rule on the trash folder. And I am pretty sure my mailserver does not play any role in this. I strongly suspect this is caused by Thunderbird.

Comment: I dont use tags, but I did one as a test, moved it to Trash and the tag stayed.  I moved it out of the trash and the tag stayed.  Tested on version 78.8 on Windows, havent tried a Linux machine yet.  This definitely sounds Thunderbird specific.  It could be a bug, version related, or however you are automatically applying your tags.

Comment: Try to compact the Trash. Thunderbird might detect and fix an anomaly while doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your index file for trash folder is corrupt. This file would be called `Trash.msf` and it would be somewhere in your Thunderbird profile directory (e.g. `/home/xxx/.thunderbird/yyy/Mail` on Linux, `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\yyy\Mail` or similar on Windows).

Close Thunderbird and delete this file. Thunderbird will automatically recreate it on next use.

**Important**: Before making any changes, back up your Thunderbird profile directory.